# Push up keyboard on screen

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, keyboard

I have a problem with my Flash App on Android, this app requires installing Adobe Air on Android before running. The keyboard pushing issue has troubled me for a while however I can't find a solution.

As you know, while triggering any text box, the keyboard, no matter built-in one or others will push the screen up to a few then you can see what you are typing. However, on my app, when I trigger the built-in keyboard, it covers the half screen meanwhile I can't see what I am typing.

Could anyone can give a light so I can completely this problem for 2 years? Is this something I can do with action script or Flash?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the textfield type that you are having trouble with? I remember that spark textfields had some issue with panning. It should definitely work with flash textfields or mx textfields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.xml file, find `<softKeyboardBehavior>` and make sure it is set to `pan`. That setting is what enables this feature. It works on Flex text inputs and I believe it works on `TextField` in AS3 projects. Don't believe I have tested it on any others.

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks for your comment, I have tried both pan and none but the issue is still, anyway I will try something else. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use to add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` to your Activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
Also go through [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft)

Comment: Hi Jyomin, thanks for your comment. However as mentioned, our product is not native Android but on Flash and Action Script3. Thanks again.

Comment: you said you're using Adobe AIR, in your android manifest xml you can declare special OS specific properties for android, iOS etc. see here [click](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc.html)

Comment: FWIW (the post is really old), AIR does not allow one to override the setting for android:windowSoftInputMode (as mentioned here https://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffe.html#WSfffb011ac560372f-5d0f4f25128cc9cd0cb-7ffc)

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation

[link]http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSfffb011ac560372f6bc38fcc12e0166e73b-7ffe.html